# How to add an image to thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

How to add an image from the templates / image / valyaev.png folder to thymeleaf, use several options, but the image itself does not appear, only the outline of the image or just a tick appears

[image]

I can add it using addInline, but I cannot perform any operations on the image, so I want to add through thymeleaf itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you copy it in the path static/images and then use the following statement:

```
<img 
th:src="@{/images/valayev.jpg}"
```

Comment: if add it to static, need to set the path @ {/ static / images / valayev.jpg}? And what is the difference?

Comment: No, just use the statement from above. It automatically looks for the image folder within the static folder. And a image belongs to "static" anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes thymeleaf does not take static image path ,in that case use base 64 of that image.

```
<img th:src="@{data:image/png;base64,YOUR IMAGE BASE 64}
```